# File upload from client side without use Fileupload controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [upload file from client to server without openFile dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578803/upload-file-from-client-to-server-without-openfile-dialog)

I want to upload file on server, but i have just path of file(Local path like : `D:\FolderName\FileName.txt)`. Is there any way to upload Local systems file on server with file path. I tried with server side but not possible. Is it possible through javascript/Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand what you want to do.  I'm assuming you have a file on the client machine and want to uploaded it via HTTP to a server as if you were using a file upload element on a web form, but you don't want to use the browser.

I'd use the command line "curl" command.  check out http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

Comment: Let me clear what i want, I am exporting .csv file, in csv file there have one column filepath. when i upload this .csv file, i fetch all data and save into database as well as i want to upload file on server with filepath(like: D:\Foldername\Filename.txt). This file path belong to client system. but i am coding on server side. so it search file path on server. It does't find that file on server.because file is on client system.

Comment: OK.  So the full path to the file located on the client machine is stored on the server, and you want the server to instruct the client to upload the file.   I suppose you could set the value in the web form file upload field and then submit the form via javascript/jQuery.  Am I understanding the file path / file location situation correctly?