# upload file from client to server without openFile dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i am trying to create an aspx page where i can directly upload a file from the client to the server without user intervention. I would like to do something like when the user specifies the file path in the url, that particular file must be uploaded to the server.

example:
ht.tp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/File_upload/File_Uploader.aspx?upload=C:/sample.csv&type=csv

The user can change the value after upload and what ever file he is specifying, it will be needed to be uploaded onto the server which is located at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

this is just a trial to check if the csv file is being created on the server or not, and it is not being created.

i just want to copy the file on the client side to the server side and it has to be only by the aspx page in the format specified above.
if there is any other good way then please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Usually it's enough to post the same answer just once (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545227/file-upload-from-client-side-without-use-fileupload-controls) :)

Answer (score 4):

It's **not** possible to upload a file without user interaction. He has to do an explicit action: drag & drop or select a file with a dialog window.

This is because **security reasons**, imagine if a HTML page could upload to a remote server any file it wants, without the user has to select which one: it could upload user documents, settings, passwords or whatever it's accessible to the Windows user that run the browser. For the same reason even the `value` attribute often is ignored and not every browser handles the `accept` attribute too (you may, more or less, force a user to select the file you want before he can continue). For what I remember older versions of Firefox didn't even allow to programmatically click an `input` tag to upload files.

Comment: Seen what you did there (bold 'not') :D

Comment: @thisMayhem I am curious. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @subirkumarsao: if you mean, how did I see the bold action, I was reading the answer, then it gave me a warning saying the post was modified, I reloaded and BANG! you're bold.

Comment: @thisMayhem I thought you were not agreeing to the post and that there was a possible way to do it. Its ok. I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

You should post the contents of the file.

That is what the browser does when using the file upload dialog. The browser opens the file and sends the contents over HTTP.

For example, you can post the contents using `wget --post-file=file.txt`. On the server, you can then read the POST data to retrieve the contents of the file.

Comment: Yes but he can't read the content of an arbitrary file (from an HTML page). I mean: he could (of course) do that from a shell script, an application or whatever but it can't be done from a HTML page itself.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I want same as you told. it will be very helpfull if you can provide me sample code. basically my requirement is different. i will read File Path from .csv file and on the base of "filepath" will upload on server.