# How can I upload files, given their paths, using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to be able to upload a file, parse the file, and then upload some more files that are listed in the first file. Is this possible?

Say I upload 'animals.csv' which contains a list of animals and some information about them, including the paths to their images. Can I parse this file and get the images listed?

I know how to upload a file using an  but is it possible to automatically upload some more files given their paths?

Comment: JS doesn't have access to the local file system If it did, that would be a ***huge*** security hole in the browser.

Comment: As @jsve said it is a ***massive*** security hole and isn't possible

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid not. Here's a similar question:
[upload file from client to server without openFile dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578803/upload-file-from-client-to-server-without-openfile-dialog)

The main issue is security. The browsers don't want to be a vector for viruses that would steal files from people's machines.

Your choices are limited to having users drag and drop files or select them from a dialog. Chrome also has a feature which will let users drag and drop folders not just files ([upload file from client to server without openFile dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578803/upload-file-from-client-to-server-without-openfile-dialog)), but i think still only Chrome supports that and the user still has to at least choose or drag the folder.